# Assign value to Date Control in InfoPath form programmatically

Tags: development, infopath

I need to assign a calculated value to date field in infopath form. I am unable to assign the value as I get "schema validation found non- datatype errors" error. The following is my code:

```
    int periodOfWarranty = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SecWarrantyDetails/my:txtPeriodofWarranty", NamespaceManager).ValueAsInt;
    DateTime startDate = (MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SecWarrantyDetails/my:dpWarrantyStartDate", NamespaceManager).ValueAsDateTime).Date;
    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddYears(periodOfWarranty).Date;
    MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SecWarrantyDetails/my:dpWarrantyEndDate", NamespaceManager).SetValue(endDate.ToString("d"));
```

Please guide me regarding the error in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mancy,

Following should help:

```
XPathNavigator endDateNode = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SecWarrantyDetails/my:dpWarrantyEndDate", NamespaceManager);

if (endDateNode.MoveToAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
   endDateNode.DeleteSelf();

endDateNode.SetValue(endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

InfoPath Date control do not accept any other format than "yyyy-MM-dd", also sometime it give the validation error because of nil attribute.. So removing the nil attribute before setting value..

Source: 
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/9400.aspx